# Unity [UNET] Sync non-player object transform

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

I have a question regarding the UNET system.

There are some objects in the scene that can be picked. I want to synchronize transform that object when a player picks it up.

The object has a `NetworkIdentity` component with `LocalPlayerAuthority` checked. It also has a `NetworkTransform` script, but the transform synchronizes only from host to clients, not the other way around. So if I move the object on the host side all clients see the change, but if the client moves it only that particular client sees the change. What do I need to do in order to make it synchronized on both sides?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I already solved this problem.

What I had to do is to `AssignLocalAuthority` of the non-player object by using player object.

Comment: will you like to share the code snippet in the answer too? i am encouting the same problem but don't how to set it.Thanks

Comment: On the player object, call `AssignLocalAuthority` in a command function (to invoke it on the host side) with the parameter of the netId of the non-player object. You can get netId from the NetworkIdentity component. 

I assign authority on a non-player object like this. Hope it helps:               `NetworkManagerVR.Instance.localNetworkPlayer.CmdAssignObjectAuthority(GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().netId);`

Comment: Thanks, but you should add it in the answer, for future user also.

Comment: I check that non-player object authority automatically assign to host. Is this correct? because if i made host then i can interact with non-player object directly and their position/rot sync across network smoothly. while same is not true for the client